# Retrieve inserted data from Oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I need to create a Windows service in C# that will get the inserted values from a Oracle database and convert them into XML.

My service will stay active and detect the data that is inserted in different tables. I will need to get those values and store them in a object.

I have tested Data Change Notification (DCN), it works fine but I only get the notification, can't get the inserted values.

Let me know if you need any code.

Is it possible to get the values that were inserted in the database?

Thank you.

**LE:**
I have tested DCN using the HR schema.
Below is the C# code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    
    cmd.AddRowid = true;
    OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
    cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnMyNotificaton);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds, tablename);
    dataGrid1.SetDataBinding(ds,tablename);
    
    Show();
    Refresh();
}

public static void OnMyNotificaton(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs args) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Result set has changed.", "Notification Alert",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

Also, this is the Insert statement used for test:

```
update employees set salary=salary+10 where employee_id=100 or employee_id=101;
commit;
```

Using the above code, I get notified when there is a row inserted in the database. But I want to get the values from that inserted row and put them into an object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements you are using; a minimal example of your C# code; any setup code necessary for the DCN; an example of the return values you are getting from the DCN; an example of your expected output.

Comment: DCN should give you the `ROWID` for the row that changed which would let you get the information that changed.  Is that unacceptable in your environment for some reason?

Comment: you've said, you are writing a service. Bu I see `Form1`

Comment: so what is the problem? Once you set notification, intercept the change here `public static void OnMyNotificaton(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)`. Create models into which each record will be populated. Make them serializable. Pick your serialization technique. Setup service locator to retrieve appropriate model and appropriate loader for that model. your `args` will be giving you exact location of changed data, where you can retrieve it. Retrieve it, serialize it and save it the way you want. Possibly, you need to setup queue where you can store incoming changes.......

Comment: ..... and then process them using producer-consumer pattern. I feel that entity framework will be perfect here. You will have the models and retrieval, just add serialization.

Comment: My database will get inserted values in multiple tables. I want to know if I can take those inserted values from multiple tables and store them in an object using DCN. @T.S., yes I'm working on a Windows Service, but first I want to test on my local database before moving the code on other database.